# Does the Double Tap perk from Zombies make rapid fire useless?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I've noticed when you have Double Tap root beer and the Locus, you load in each shot *super* fast. Does having the Rapid Fire attachment on the Locus (or any other applicable gun) along with the Double Tap perk make Rapid Fire useless, or are the two improved reload speeds combined?

Additionally, does Double Tap increase the max fire rate per second of pistols, and does it even affect rocket launchers?

Comment: Are you referring to Double Tapp root beer, from the zombies mode?

Comment: I am, is there a different Double Tap? I'd edit my statement to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Double Tapp will affect all weapons, as per the [wiki entry](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Double_Tap_Root_Beer) (emphasis mine):

> Double Tap increases the rate of fire (and recoil accordingly) of **all weapons** by 33% and doubles bullet damage (2.0 version only). It also allows the player to lay down equipment such as Claymores faster and makes players operate bolt-action rifles, pump-action shotguns (as well as re-chambering them), and Wonder Weapons such as the Wrath of the Ancients noticeably quicker, as well as raising the firecap.

Double Tapp will also synthesize with Rapid Fire, as per this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/CODZombies/comments/472s5o/double_tap_rapid_fire/). Rapid Fire apparently adds 10-15% on top of the 25-33% boost provided by Double Tapp.